# Contact form / newsletter signup compatible with Brave Browser

Tags: newsletter

Seems every contact form / newsletter signup wants to run a million external scripts and trackers. Pretty annoying. Any suggestions for a plugin which is entirely stand alone?

Comment: What do you mean with "a million external scripts and trackers"? Plugins like Contactform7, Ninjaforms or Gavityforms are pretty clean in my opinion.

Comment: specifically 'the newsletter plugin' stopped working in brave, also facing frustration using jetpack. Contactform7 has been personal go to, will continue.. will continue trial and error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Happyforms](https://happyforms.io/)? It doesn't come with any external scripts. All the scripts it runs are from within the plugin itself or scripts that comes included with WordPress.